# How do IP addresses work in terms of servers and domains?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ip-address, minecraft

I am building a Minecraft server and the computer running it has a generic 192.168 IP. Do I need to change it when I am putting into Google Domains (so it does not confuse it with another one)? If so, how do I change my IP address so the Google Domains, and sequentially, Minecraft, does not confuse this with another IP. Is this even how it works? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your 192.168 IP address is an address assigned on your local network. It is so that computers connected to your local network can find each other. If you are connected to the Internet, you will also have a public IP address. You can check that by typing **what is my IP address** in Google search. This address is used by computers on the Internet to find your local network. Unless you have a static IP address from your Internet Service Provider, your public IP address will change from time to time. Having a static IP address means that your public IP will not change and therefore you can direct users to that IP address, or attach a domain name to the IP address in your DNS records to make it easier for users to remember. You'll also need firewall rules amended on your router to allow traffic in to your private network through whatever port is used by your Minecraft server.

Comment: This question is way too broad and the original poster seems a bit in over their heads. Any answer is really never going to “answer” the core question. Looking at your own answer, these answers only lead to more questions. It’s best to simply leave a comment that explains some things and just say, “This is more complicated than you might think if you are asking a question like this.”

Comment: @giacomo that does not make the answer bad or wrong.  It confused me why people are so quick to down vote answers which are not wrong.

Comment: @davidgo Because it encourages questions that are bad. The question is bad, the answer can’t be good. Especially since if the question is bad, the question will be closed and thus the question and any answers posted go away. Thus a wasted effort. Please do not answer bad questions; just leave comments.

Comment: @giacomo1968 Sorry, I don't think this question is question is bad. The author just does not have the knowledge to ask a more precise question. Doesn't mean we should not help.   I don't care if questions go away - the goal is to help people who need it.